# How to hide swagger errors?

Tags: swagger-ui

Our swagger.json is lightly modified to display extra information from our api, this results in errors that are shown on top of the screen, but the api below is displayed fine. We would like to hide these errors, as they distract the developers that consume our documentation.

I've tried to set validatorUrl to false/null/undefined but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using a very old version of Swagger UI. Can you try the [latest version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases) (4.3.12 as of this writing) and see if the resolver errors are fixed there? Also check your swagger.json for syntax errors in https://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: Thank at the end i decided to fix the old syntax, i have been using different tutorials which ended up in the mixed syntax for different versions of Swagger 2.0 and jsonapi 3.0.0